# "of whom" vs. "of which" when referring to people AND things

Tags: relative-pronouns, of-genitive

In the following sentence, *partners* includes both people (such as subject matter experts) and organizations (such as schools):

"These courses are taught by our partners, **all of [whom/which]** are industry leaders."

Would I be better off using *whom* or *which*?

Or, alternatively, could I make the sentence sound a bit less formal by rephrasing it as:

"These courses are taught by our partners, **[who/which] are all** industry leaders."

...or would this change the meaning/emphasis?

Comment: This is a problem engendered by using the same uninformative term (_partner_) to cover both people and organizations. That wouldn't matter, except that now you want a relative clause to refer to both of them with one pied-piped _wh_-word. Solution - don't use a relative clause; use a semicolon. _... our partners; all of them are industry leaders._

Comment: The context shows you're referring to both people and organizations?  (If not, then it could be good to specify, e.g. "our partner providers and companies.")  So, you're asking, should the set of people and organizations be treated like people, or like organizations?  Interesting question.  My opinion (non-expert): you get to decide whether you want to treat the organizations as assemblages of people, or whether the organization aspect is what you want to emphasize.  For example, as an education advocate, I work with school districts, which are assemblages of people, so I'd choose "whom."